# Cloudfoundry server run on Apache2

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have question about cloudfoundry (CF) server ..
Will it be possinle if I run CF-server on apache2/httpd web server?
any way for it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I see two possibilities:

1) You want to run the Cloud Foundry open-source PaaS under apache. This is not possible, as Cloud Foundry is comprised of multiple standalone daemons that run on Linux.

2) You want to run websites that use apache on the Cloud Foundry PaaS. Apache is not provided as a "runtime" on CloudFoundry.com, but is used for the PHP runtime/framework in the open-source Cloud Foundry at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap.

If your question is related to the open-source Cloud Foundry project (and not the CloudFoundry.com service), the best place to ask questions is the vcap-dev Google Group: http://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/group/vcap-dev/

Comment: my case is :
- I have some apps writen on java which run under Tomcat Container where configured with mod_jk on apache2 on Ubuntu 11.10 server.
- Then I want to install CF from dustin kirkland link http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/08/howto-install-cloudfoundry-server-paas.html ,
- The consequence is will be there 2 web server run on port 80 (apache2 and nginx from CF installation) 
- I have an idea to change nginx to port 81 then use mod_proxy on apache2 to make a virtual host for redirecting port 81 to 80 ..
any idea?

Comment: Dustin's post is significantly outdated now and unfortunately the Cloud Foundry package he refers to have not been updated for some time.

I would recommend installing Cloud Foundry from vcap on github using the dev_setup script or BOSH. Note that these are not particularly "simple" to do at the moment. Once you have an environment deployed, push your Tomcat app using the template from Eric Bottard on Github https://github.com/ericbottard/cloudfoundry-tomcat-7